# How to create a pre-save signal in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a model which generates a verification token:

```
class VerificationTokenModel(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='verification_token')
    verification_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=False, unique=True)
    token_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TOKEN_TYPE)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(default=get_current_time)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now what I want is that no user can generate another access token within 5 minutes again and user can generate token maximum 10 times a day.
How can I achieve this using pre-save signal?

Comment: Why do you want to use `pre-save` signals for this? Sigals are usually not a good idea. They have a (limited) number of useful cases, but are "overused". See https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: I dont want to create token if the user has already created one within a time limit

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off overriding `clean()` (which, nb, isn't called if you call `.save()` directly) or `save()` in your model:

```
class VerificationTokenModel(BaseModel):
    # ...
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # Do check only on initial save
            self._check_pre_save()
        return super().save(**kwargs)

    def _check_pre_save(self):
        if VerificationTokenModel.objects.filter(user=self.user, expiry_time__gt=now() - timedelta(minutes=5)).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Too soon!")
        # and other conditions...
```